# Limit Scene Kit Camera Rotation around a single (y) axis in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

So I have a sphere in scene kit and currently, I am orbiting the sphere with the default .allowsCameraControl = true. I want to limit the orbit of the camera to only orbit the Y-axis (basically it will look like a globe spinning).

I have tried messing around with spinning the actual sphere with pan gestures, but that seemed to complicate things rather quickly and I would like to keep the default physics and gestures involved with .allowsCameraControl = true if at all possible.

Below is what I have currently. Thanks!

```
    private func createSceneHelpers() {
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
    }

    private func createCamera() {
        cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 5)
        myScene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the `SCNCameraController` class and its `maximumVerticalAngle` property. The `SCNInteractionModeOrbitTurntable` interaction mode is also of interest. Note that if the online documentation is lacking, the documentation in SceneKit's header file as more often up-to-date.